# Is it possible parse a model into a modelform?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

If I had a `person model` and a `person modelform`, could I use the model to insert the values into the modelform and check if it is_valid?

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model:
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class PersonModelForm(ModelForm):
   model = Person
   fields = '__all__'
```

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   name = request.POST['name']
   age = request.POST['age']

   person = Person(name=name, age=age)
   person_form = PersonModelForm(INSERT HERE SOMETHING)
   if person_form.is_valid:
      print('person_form is valid')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass it as the `instance` kwarg:

```
person_form = PersonModelForm(instance=person)
```

But you most often don't need to do that, since the whole point of a `ModelForm` is that it populates the instance into itself automatically from the POSTed form from the request.

And, even manually doing that is more convenient than what you had before:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    person_form = PersonModelForm(request.POST)
    if person_form.is_valid:
        print('person_form is valid')
```